# Работа со скроллом

Tags: html, css

Есть страница у которой сразу отображен скролл. На странице при нажатии на кнопку появляется pop-up у которого тоже есть скролл. Если у главной страницы не скрывать скролл то отображается 2 скролла, что некорректно. (Если скрывать скролл на первой странице, то заметно что станица сдвигается вправо.)

Как так сделать чтобы страница не сдвигалась?

Answer (score 0):

Когда скрываете скрол добавляйте `margin-right: 17px`

Comment: В моём браузере ширина скролла `9px`, так что ваше решение не исправит проблему